# How to match user height between VR and AR?

Tags: mrtk

I asked this some time ago on GitHub and was asked to move the question here, so I will.

From my experience, starting a game with a **Hololens makes the camera start at 0,0,0** in the scene. When starting **with an HMD, the head has approximately the correct height**, which can also be adjusted in the Mixed Reality Portal if not perfect.
If those two were to meet in a networked environment, one would see the other at his feet or high up in the air when viewed the other way around.
**To get those two to meet at eye level, you either raise one up or lower the other down. No matter the case, you need to know by how much**.
The Hololens does not have an internal height representation, you could calculate it from the generated spatial mesh at best. The HMD on the other hand does have an information about it's height, a base height even, otherwise I couldn't configure that in the Portal, kneel down etc. and just be the correct height above the floor.

Now the question is, how do I read this base height for the HMD so I can lower the floor to that height, effectively setting the networked parties to eye level?

For now I have to set an arbitrary height of like 1.6 meters, but that's my colleagues standing height. I am about 1.93 meters tall

NeerajW on GitHub wanted to see if he could find an API that returns the Portal default height, but never replied.

With the Hololens 2 joining the community that's now two AR devices that might want to meet VR avatars from around the world.

How do you guys do this?

Comment: Hi @Alexees,

I am working with the team to provide an easy solution.

I'll post here when available.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, are you trying to 1-to-1 match the actual user heights? If so, you may wish to place the avatars at eye level (if they are small/hovering objects) or on the floor plane (if they are humanoid).

Since the VR user's cannot actually see the HoloLens user, this may work well. For the HoloLens user it may feel odd, presuming the VR user is visible (in the same room).

In the Holograms 250 academy course (please note this uses the legacy HoloToolkit), the app represents HoloLens users as floating clouds in VR. The VR user was represented as a small figure on an island model to the HoloLens user.

I hope this is helpful.
David

(I also have an inquiry with other members of the team to see if there are other ideas).

Comment: Yes, we are trying to 1-to-1 match them, assuming, VR and AR users are not in the same real room. Our situation is, that AR users are presented to the VR users OR AR users in other rooms as avatars. And of course everyone is presented to VR users as avatars. So the only exception are real people in the same room, since they can see each other.